# Odd Visual Studio Experience?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am running an app as a side app to a major application on an x86 Windows 8.1 tablet.  The app is written in C# 3.5 client side.  When I try to compile the app on a desktop machine, and then run the app on a tablet, the app immediately crashes.  When I compile the app on a tablet (fresh VS install), the app runs fine.  Does anyone know what setting I could be missing here?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: By chance is your app requiring the AppName.exe.config file to be in the same folder as the exe?  It may be trying to run in a different framework version without it.

Comment: Switching the app to compile to 3.5 instead of "3.5 client profile" and x86 throughout the project's build tab fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the app to compile to 3.5 instead of "3.5 client profile" and x86 throughout the project's build tab fixed the bug.